# Yii2 update column on update, and default value current timestamp in postgres

Tags: postgresql, yii2

In yii2 migration file i had create two columns

```
'updated_at' => $this->integer()->defaultValue('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
'created_at' => $this->integer()->defaultValue('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
```

But this is working in MYSQL, and it will not working in PostgreSQL?

How to create column with updating `timestamp` column when I update the row, and set default `timestamp` when I create the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior) if you want solution that wouldn't be dependent on used DBMS.

Otherwise you have to use trigger to set the current timestamp on update. See this question for more info [Update timestamp when row is updated in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035980/update-timestamp-when-row-is-updated-in-postgresql)