# Django: When will `auto_now` field not be updated?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Suppose I have a Django app backed by Postgres, and in that app I have model called `Contact` with a `DateTimeField` called `last_updated`. Suppose `last_updated` has `auto_now` set to `True`.

I know there are some circumstances in which `last_updated` will not get updated when a `Contact` record is updated:

- `Contact.objects.filter(xxx).update(yyy)` will not update `last_updated` unless `last_updated` is included in `yyy`
- `Contact.objects.bulk_update(contacts_qs, [zzz])` will not update `last_updated` unless `last_updated` is in `zzz`

Are there other ways to update modify `Contact` objects (barring accessing the DB directly)  where `last_updated` won't be updated?

Comment: `mymodelobject.save(update_fields=['no_yyy'])`

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now):

> DateField.auto_now

> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved. Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that.

So unless you are doing an unmodified save directly from the model, it is possible the field will not be automatically saved. This is why I use a Postgres trigger/function combination that handles this in the database. Also to handle data updates coming from outside Django.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm not very fluent with Postgres triggers and functions, would this be a good SO question to start from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035980/update-timestamp-when-row-is-updated-in-postgresql

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I do.