# Supabase: How to automatically update a timestamp field after updating a row?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

**What DB I am using?**

- Supabase hosted version

**What do I need?**

- After I update a row with `.update({ name: 'Middle Earth' })` method I need to
  automatically update also a timestamp in my table.

### How can I update automatically a timestamp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 1)If you already have a table use [this](https://supabase-sql.vercel.app/automatically-update-timestamp) script (provided by Supabase devs themselves):

```
create extension if not exists moddatetime schema extensions;

-- assuming the table name is "todos", and a timestamp column "updated_at"
-- this trigger will set the "updated_at" column to the current timestamp for every update
create trigger handle_updated_at before update on todos
  for each row execute procedure moddatetime (updated_at);
```

### 2)What if I don't wanna use the `moddatetime` extension?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035980/update-timestamp-when-row-is-updated-in-postgresql) stackoverflow question will give you an answer.

Comment: How do I preform this on a specific row?
i.e.
`for <row-name> row ...` doesn't work

Comment: I am sorry but to my knowledge it is not possible.